# Correlation coefficient confidence intervals

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

Using scipy.stats we can compute the correlation coefficient along with a p-value. For example using:

```
x = [1.76405235, 0.40015721, 0.97873798,
 2.2408932, 1.86755799, -0.97727788]
y = [2.71414076, 0.2488, 0.87551913,
 2.6514917, 2.01160156, 0.47699563]
def statistic(x):  # permute only `x`
     return stats.spearmanr(x, y).statistic
res_exact = stats.permutation_test((x,), statistic, permutation_type='pairings')

res_exact.pvalue
(0.10277777777777777)
```

But I would like a confidence internal for the correlation coefficient.  In R this is given by [default](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/DescTools/html/SpearmanRho.html).  What can you do in R?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18887/how-to-calculate-a-confidence-interval-for-spearmans-rank-correlation), the 95% confidence interval for the Spearman's rank correlation can be computed as follows:

```py
import math
from scipy import stats

x = [1.76405235, 0.40015721, 0.97873798, 2.2408932, 1.86755799, -0.97727788]
y = [2.71414076, 0.2488, 0.87551913, 2.6514917, 2.01160156, 0.47699563]

res = stats.spearmanr(x, y)
spearman_r = res.correlation

count = len(x)

stderr = 1.0 / math.sqrt(count - 3)
delta = 1.96 * stderr
lower = math.tanh(math.atanh(spearman_r) - delta)
upper = math.tanh(math.atanh(spearman_r) + delta)
```

where `lower` is equal to -0.1073 and `upper` to 0.9735.

It seems SciPy does not compute the confidence interval by default for the  rank correlation. Just as an additional info, I have found [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats._result_classes.PearsonRResult.confidence_interval.html) SciPy class for computing the confidence interval for the Pearson coefficient, maybe it could be helpful in the future.

Comment: How would change this for 90% or 99% confidence intervals?

Comment: It just comes out of the standard normal distribution. For a 90% confidence interval you need to replace 1.96 with 1.65. For further details take a look [here](https://sphweb.bumc.bu.edu/otlt/mph-modules/bs/bs704_confidence_intervals/bs704_confidence_intervals_print.html#:~:text=For%20the%20standard%20normal%20distribution,fall%20between%20%2D1.96%20and%201.96.) for example (table at the bottom).